# Pushing to list in realm

Tags: react-native, realm

These are my realm objects. I have Hole and Round. I am trying to populate my round with 18 hole objects in a single write but I've been stuck on this for the past few hours and I can't seem to understand where I'm going wrong.

```
class Hole extends Realm.Object {}
Hole.schema = {
  name: 'Hole',
  primaryKey:  'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    fullStroke: 'int',
    halfStroke: 'int',
    puts: 'int',
    firstPutDistance: 'int',
    penalties: 'int',
    fairway: 'string'
  },
};

class Round extends Realm.Object {}
Round.schema = {
  name: 'Round',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'string',
    done: 'string',
    holes: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Hole'}
  },
};
```

Here is my function that is attempting to push every hole into the hole property of Round. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
exportRound = () => {
  let holesObjects = realm.objects('Hole')
  if(holesObjects.length < 9){
    alert('Enter stats for at least 9 holes please')
  }
  else{
    var sortedHoles = holesObjects.sorted('id')
    currentRound = realm.objects('Round').filtered('done == "no"')
    for(var i = 1; i < holesObjects.length; i++){
      console.log(holesObjects.filtered('id == i'))
      realm.write(()=> currentRound.holes.push(holesObjects.filtered('id == {i}')) )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's error are you facing?

I found some mistake in your code.

The type of `currentRound` object is `Results`. It is not `Round` object until you retrieve each element. So it doesn't have `holes` property. You should retrieve the element contained by `Results`, like the following:

```
var currentRound = realm.objects('Round').filtered('done == "no"')[0]
```

String interpolation should be `` `id == ${i}` `` (Use backtick and `${}`). So your query should be:

```
holesObjects.filtered(`id == ${i}`)
```

`` holesObjects.filtered(`id == ${i}`) `` returns also `Results` object. You should retrieve an element first.

```
realm.write(()=> currentRound.holes.push(holesObjects.filtered(`id == ${i}`)[0]))
```

The whole code that I edited is the following:

```
exportRound = () => {
  let holesObjects = realm.objects('Hole')
  console.log(holesObjects);
  if(holesObjects.length < 9){
    alert('Enter stats for at least 9 holes please')
  }
  else{
    var sortedHoles = holesObjects.sorted('id')
    var currentRound = realm.objects('Round').filtered('done == "no"')[0]
    console.log(currentRound)
    for(var i = 1; i < holesObjects.length; i++){
      console.log(holesObjects.filtered(`id == ${i}`))
      realm.write(()=> currentRound.holes.push(holesObjects.filtered(`id == ${i}`)[0]))
    }
  }
}
```